# chart.series[id].remove() is not able to refresh legend properties of other series in highcharts/highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I remove first series from the chart i.e. chart.series[0].remove();
the legend properties for other series are not updated. i.e. legend of series 1 does not know that he is at location 0 after I have deleted series 0.

So my basic issue is that i need to update/ all series legends after I have removed a series.

How can I do this?

**Update#:
my scenaro: i have legends with cross icons (using html). if i click on close icon, that series is removed. if i click on legend name, a jQuery Dialog opens giving you functionality to update yAxis , type for that perticular series.**

Code for legend formatter:

```
 legend: {
                                enabled: true,
                                useHTML: true,
                                labelFormatter: function test() {
                                    console.log("in label fomatter");
                                        console.log("in test");
                                        console.log(this);
                                    if (this.userOptions.yAxis == 0) {
                                        return "<input type=\"button\"onclick=\"updateSeries('"+this.index+"','"+this.userOptions.yAxis+"','"+this.userOptions.type+"')\" class=\"ui-widget\" value=\"" + this.name + " (RH)\"/> <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"removeSeries(" + this.index + ")\" class=\"ui-widget\" value=\" X \" />";
                                    } else if (this.userOptions.yAxis == 1) {
                                        return "<input type=\"button\"onclick=\"updateSeries('"+this.index+"','"+this.userOptions.yAxis+"','"+this.userOptions.type+"')\" class=\"ui-widget\" value=\"" + this.name + " (LH)\"/> <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"removeSeries(" + this.index + ")\" class=\"ui-widget\" value=\" X \" />";
                                    } else if (this.userOptions.yAxis == 2) {
                                        return "<input type=\"button\"onclick=\"updateSeries('"+this.index+"','"+this.userOptions.yAxis+"','"+this.userOptions.type+"')\" class=\"ui-widget\" value=\"" + this.name + " (3rd)\"/> <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"removeSeries(" + this.index + ")\" class=\"ui-widget\" value=\" X \" />";
                                    }
                                    return "";
                                }
                            },
```

Code for remove series:

```
    function removeSeries(id) {
        console.log("in remove series");
        var chart = $('#container')
            .highcharts();
        chart.series[id].remove();
        chart.isDirtyLegend = true;
        chart.isDirtyBox = true;

        chart.legend.render();
        return;
    };
```

code for update series (I am creating a dialog box when a legend is clicked):

```
 function updateSeries(index, yAxis, type) {
                console.log("in update series");
                //console.log(chart.get())
                console.log("in update series"+index);
                var chart = $('#container')
                .highcharts();
                chart.isDirtyLegend = true;
                chart.isDirtyBox = true;
                chart.legend.render();
                console.log(chart.get("USSW1Y:3M Carry").index);
                $("#dialog")
                    .dialog("open");
                $("#legendTable")
                    .html("");
                $('#legendTable')
                    .append("<tr><td>Axis</td><td><select onchange=\"updateSeriesFromDialog(" + index + ")\" id=\"legendAxis\" name=\"legendAxis\"><option value=\"0\">1</option><option value=\"1\">2</option><option value=\"2\">3</option></select></td><td>Type</td><td><select onchange=\"updateSeriesFromDialog(" + index + ")\" id=\"legendType\" name=\"legendType\"><option value=\"line\">Line</option><option value=\"column\">Column</option><option value=\"bar\">Bar</option><option value=\"scatter\">Scatter</option><option value=\"area\">Area</option><option value=\"spline\">Spline</option><option value=\"areaspline\">Area Spline</option></select></td></tr>");
                $("#legendAxis").val(yAxis);
                $("#legendType").val(type);
                return;
            };

            function updateSeriesFromDialog(id){
                 var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                 console.log("in update from Dialog series");
                 chart.series[id].update({
                     type: $("#legendType").val(),
                     yAxis: parseInt($("#legendAxis").val())
                });
            };
```

Comment: Why series should know the location? Highcharts series don't know the location as I know. Some live demo with the issue would be great.

Comment: i use this.index for each series as identifier to perform operations like update yAxis, type etc. Is this the correct approach? If know then how can i refer to a series. i cannot give a live demo as JSFiddle is blocked here.

Comment: Then how about sharing code related to the Highcharts? Instead of index, use `series.xAxis` or `series.yAxis` to update related axes.

Comment: updated the code. have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of basing on index, use `id` for series, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/14jL9no0/3/

So, each series now has an ID:

```
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        id: "one",
        yAxis: 0
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].reverse(),
        id: "two",
        yAxis: 1
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].sort(),
        id: "three",
        yAxis: 2
    }]
```

Now, pass on that ID to your methods:

```
 return "<input type=\"button\"onclick=\"updateSeries('" + this.index + "','" + this.userOptions.yAxis + "','" + this.userOptions.type + "')\" class=\"ui-widget\" value=\"" + this.name + " (3rd)\"/> <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"removeSeries('" + this.options.id + "')\" class=\"ui-widget\" value=\" X \" />";
```

And last step, `removeSeries` can get series from the chart:

```
function removeSeries(id) {
  console.log("in remove series");
  var chart = $('#container')
    .highcharts();
  chart.get(id).remove();

  return;
};
```

Now, the same you can do in updating series. Instead of passing multiple arguments, pass just an ID, and then use `chart.get(id)` to get corresponding series.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `render()` on the chart's legend to re-render it:

```
chart.legend.render();
```

Comment: its not refreshing my legend. Dont know if its the code or not.